# Is there anything wrong about attaching event handlers via attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

This sounds like a bit of a beginner's question: 
You can attach event handlers either via `addEventListener` `attachEvent` or the `$().event(handler)`

Or you can do it by assigning an attribute onclick

```
<a onclick="doSomething()"/>
```

So I was wonderin if there is anything particularly wrong with using the attribute method. It sounds wrong, but I don't see how it would impede anything. Especially because it makes it very easy to pass arguments

Seperation of concerns would be one good reason not to do it.
I have a seminar on jQuery for beginners, so I was looking for some other problems so I can give to people. "Cause I said so" isn't really my style. I know this sounds like an open ended question, but I am pretty sure there are definitive reasons for not doing this.

Comment: It's always nice to see separation of logic from presentation.

Comment: Next to "separation of concerns" comes "does not allow multiple listeners"

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the [traditional model](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Why Binding Events Inline Is Bad**

- it's hard to maintain the code when you want to make some change
- your code can't be cached if it's large(reason explained in comment section)
- you can't reuse your event handler
- you're mixing up the `content layer` and `behaviour layer` which makes your code lacks of logic
- the event handler will be executed using `eval` in `global` namespace, the two things you have to avoid in JavaScript
- it's hard to support no-javascript situation, makes `progress enhancement` difficult

**So**

Always add .js file and .css file externally, and bind events using framework to make your code work cross-browser.

**Further reading**

[Why Inline CSS And JavaScript Code Is Such A Bad Thing](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/)

[Unobstrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

[The Three Layer in Webpage Development](http://webdesign.about.com/od/intermediatetutorials/a/aa010707.htm)

[Progress Enhancement](http://alistapart.com/article/understandingprogressiveenhancement)

Comment: Why do you think inline events do not work with dynamically added elements? What do you mean by "code is not cached"? Also please add a few of the reasons that I cannot imagine.

Comment: You *can* bind multiple events in that way.  You can also bind multiple event handlers to each event.

Comment: there is a misunderstanding i think those `onevent` handler should be added to html tag directly, i remove that item. For caching thing, if you put every event handler to html tag and that webpage is served dynamically, how can that be served? unless you put them into separate static file.

Comment: It still says you can't bind multiple events when you can.  The caching thing is stretching the truth, in fairness, and you still have the "way more reason than you can image..." which is very vague.  Please remove that and list some of the reasons instead :)

Comment: @jasonslyvia: The caching concern seems to be the same as for inline scripts - it can be easily avoided by loading an external script and calling functions therein. Same thing for reuse of code - you can simply put it in a function.

Comment: @Bergi yeah i agree with you, but consider the extreme situation there will be a filesize increase for webpage

Comment: @jasonslyvia: Your fifth point is wrong. `eval` is not used, the code is parsed once when the page is loaded and interpreted every time the event fires. "Global scope" is [not exactly true](http://jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html), though while you probably mean the right thing it has nothing to do with avoiding global namespace pollution

Comment: Good answer! You nailed it :) +1

Answer (score 3):

This is called [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). The goals of Unobtrusive JavaScript are:

1. Separation of functionality (the "behavior layer") from a Web page's structure/content and presentation
2. Best practices to avoid the problems of traditional JavaScript programming (such as browser inconsistencies and lack of scalability)
3. Progressive enhancement to support user agents that may not support advanced JavaScript functionality

Basically, if a user-agent does not support JavaScript, it should never know it was there.

Answer (score 0):

To explain in simple terms, there is nothing 'wrong' in doing that. It's semantically good practice to separate markup, styles and the scripts. So, the same reason why inline styles are not 'wrong' but not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

At last it comes down to the [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Most things that are possible with the [advanced model](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) can be done with the [inline event attributes](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html) as well - they only get more complicated:

- You can bind multiple listeners (`onclick="doA(); doB()"`), but you need to know of all of them in before
- When dynamically generating such attributes (e.g. in HTML strings), you have to make use of code strings
- To call external functions, they must be in the global scope

If you are not using inline events, it simplifies coding/maintaining code, allows better program design (and facilitates [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)), and reduces file sizes.

The [traditional model](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) with the `onEvent` DOM attributes does take care of the last two points. Assigning multiple listeners (of same type) on the same element is possible (even without knowing each other), but still very cumbersome.

The advanced event binding with `addEventListener` allows greater flexibility. You do not need to take care of other event listeners (aside from stopping propagation), and it allows one thing that was not possible before: handling events in the capture phase.